# Unity objects and animation

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, cinema-4d

I am using Cinema 4d to create objects And Animations. Is There anyway to import them into unity as a 3d object formats and animation?
just like 3dsmax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity3d official docs provide detail guide
[Importing Objects From Cinema 4D](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectCinema4D.html)